# Send Data Every 10 minutes

Tags: iphone

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    




// Override point for customization after application launch.

locmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
[locmanager setDelegate:self]; 
[locmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters];
//[locmanager setDistanceFilter:10];
updateTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:600 target:self selector:@selector(startUpdating) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:updateTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

 -(void)startUpdating
{
[locmanager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{ 
       if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;


  CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];
 currentdate=[[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];
   latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", loc.latitude];
 longitude= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", loc.longitude];
//Call to webservice to send data
}
```

I want to send coordinates to web service every 10 minutes.Tried doing this but this is not working.My application is registered to get location updates in background.Please suggest me changes that need to be done to this program.

Comment: What does *it's not working* mean? Post any error messages or output.

Comment: Provide more information. What do you expect to happen, what actually happens?

Comment: I want to send GPS coordinates every 10 minutes to a server.

Comment: It should send the coordinates exactly after 10 minutes.The program is not crashing but I am not getting any data.It keps on running without sending any data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done something similar to this by using NSUserDefaults to record the datetime it last sent to the server and using NSTimeInterval to compare between the updated location's datestamp and this value. I am using 30s but you can adjust upwards. It's a bit of hack but it works with background running etc.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
}

    updatedLocation = [newLocation retain];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDate *myDate = (NSDate *)[prefs objectForKey:@"myDateKey"];

    NSDate *lastDate = (NSDate *)newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval theDiff = [lastDate timeIntervalSinceDate:myDate];

    if (theDiff > 30.0f || myDate == nil){
             //do your webservices stuff here
            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [prefs setObject:lastDate forKey:@"myDateKey"];
            [prefs synchronize];

    }
```

Comment: This code is amazing and I am using this in my application.Thanks a lot Robert.

Comment: I have some problem using this could you please help.

Comment: Robert could you please help me with this.I have some issues using this.

Comment: Your other question seems to have disappeared.

Comment: The data is not send every 10 minutes.Sometimes my phone is not sending any data for long hours when it is stationary.Do you find any reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop updating in your location manager.  It will keep calling didUpdateToLocation unless you stop it after it returns the first time.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
etc...
```

Comment: What if I call location manager once and after that call my web service every 10 minutes.Will that be a right approach.This way I will ignore all that data that I got within 10 minutes.I want my application to be run in background as well.Please suggest a right way to do this.

Comment: That would work but would of course upload the same coordinates every 10 minutes rather than updated co-ordinates.  You can do it that way or the way I showed above if you want a newer location.

Comment: Well in the didUpdateToLocation function you would immeditely stop the updates then upload what you have to the server.