# Send data through socket every x minutes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sockets, background

I have a location based iOS app and I want to interact with a server every x minutes.

I read this post: [Send Data Every 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098663/send-data-every-10-minutes)

But I have to send an empty header to my server even if there is no location update for a while because I have to read any pending commands from my server and it only writes back if you write first.

This has to work even if the app is running background.

What should be the best way to perform this? Using a timer?

I've already made this kind of stuff on Android but I'm a little stuck on how to do here.

Cheers,

Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a NSTimer when the app is running, but you can't do that when the app is in background. The iOS reference contains all the possible uses of multitasking: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

As you can see, there's a small amount of possible operations (voip, audio or location) that are able to wake up your app.

Comment: And if I register my app for location updates as i'm currently doing will my timer been called? Or will my app only been waken up when there are new coordinates?